# i have accidently delete my sceret key form settings.py in django

Tags: python, django, secret-key

while pulling from git hub i lost my secret key which i have updated. is there any way to obtain secret key for the same project.

while pulling from git hub i lost my secret key which i have updated. is there any way to obtain secret key for the same project.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

run : `python manage.py shell`
write and enter the following lines sequentially:

```
from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key
print(get_random_secret_key())
exit()
```

copy this secret_key to your settings.py SECRET_KEY. And reload this server. If it will not work, refresh the page with `ctrl+shift+r`, delete cache.

If it will not work again, try to remove all rows from django_session table where in your database.

My English skills are not good, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to restore a secret key unless you remember a place where you stored it. But I don't think that's critical that you lost it, just set a new one. It should mostly affect the existing users' sessions, i.e. currently logged in users will be signed-out and will have to sign in again.

See what `SECRET_KEY` is used for [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-SECRET_KEY)

> Secret keys are not used for passwords of users and key rotation will not affect them.

Comment: i cant run my local server

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: its ask for secret key

Comment: So set a new `SECRET_KEY`

Comment: is it possible to set a new secret key for existing project?? if so, how?

Comment: Well, that's what my answer says :) Just assign some new random string to `SECRET_KEY` in `settings.py`. How did you set it previously?

Comment: it was set by django not me, by running python manage.py startproject

Comment: ok, it set it to `settings.py`, right? just set it yourself now, random string (the uglier the better)

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: when i type python manage.py runserver nothing happens

Comment: It doesn't say anything?

Comment: nope, nothing.      django_web2>python manage.py runserver

D:\django_web2>

Comment: what did you change? please show how you set your `SECRET_KEY`